# XMLParsing in IPhone for Login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, xml-parsing

I am following the below link to parse the xml for login page, http://yksoftware.blogspot.in/2010/04/iphone-programming-tutorial-xml-login.html

whenever i enter the fields of username and password, it displays login failed only even when i provide the correct username and password in the textfields.
In the following code when i keep the breakpoint in loginPressed method and check, it is not entering the for loop,

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mailrail.net/sample.aspx?username=naresh&password=reddy"];
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"User"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentUser =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentPassword =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"User"]) {
        [item setObject:currentUser forKey:@"username"];
        [item setObject:currentPassword forKey:@"password"];
        [users addObject:[item copy]];

    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
        [currentUser appendString:string];
    }
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"password"]) {
        [currentPassword appendString:string];
    }
}

-(IBAction)loginPressed:(id)sender{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *val in users) {                    
        NSMutableString *usrname = [val objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"%@",usrname);
        NSMutableString *psswrd = [val objectForKey:@"password"];
        usrname=[usrname stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        usrname=[usrname stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
        psswrd=[psswrd stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        psswrd=[psswrd stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
        if([usrname isEqualToString:[txtUsername text]]&&[psswrd isEqualToString:[txtPassword text]]){
            [lblLoginStatus setText:@"Login Successful!!"];
            return;
        }
    }
    [lblLoginStatus setText:@"login failed"];
    return;
}

-(IBAction)returnClicked:(UITextField *)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)clickBackground:(id)sender{

    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    [txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and returns with login failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so log out usrname, textUsername, psswrd ant txtPassword to check what's going on.

Comment: @Mrithula, users is NSMUtableArray for storing the username and password.

Comment: ok so in users u have an NSmutableDictory? if yes then u should get it like this for(int i = 0; i < [users count]; i++){ NSMutableDictionary * dict = [users objectAtIndex:i]; /////}

Comment: @Mrithula, I have entered the entire code now, u can check it.

Comment: ok can i ask u something, will u have more than one user?

Comment: @Mrithula,Yes we have more than one user, but in the url we just kept one user's username and password for testing.

Comment: can u check something, in ur didStartElement, theres a dict and i guess u might get the values for uername and password in that. if u get it, then u can simply create a dict in didStartElement and set values to it and add it to ur array.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to solve the parsing how to parse some thing from xml using parser and then think for loging beacuse if you have made parser then it is easy to use login form. Below is the following tutorial for XML parsing it is detailed and help you can get help.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just check this

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
currentElement = [elementName copy];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"User"]) {
     NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [item setValue:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"username"] forKey:@"username"];
      [item setValue:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"password"] forKey:@"password"];
     [users addObject:item];
}
```

}

please del other two delegates and check this

Comment: ,I checked with the method, still it gives login failed and i also checked using log to check the username and password it was not printing in the console. I think i have recheck the entire code or look the xmlparsing from the scratch once.Any suggestions from your side will be appreciated.